# How do you set TextField text to text received from JSON file? (Flutter)

Tags: json, flutter

I am pretty new to flutter and I was wondering how I could set the the TextField text using a `TextEditController` (named crText) to a text received from a JSON file. The text from the JSON file is stored in chemText which is a String. The `getData` method, which has all the querying functions is called during an `onPressed` method in the "Search" icon. The text in the TextField is desired to be changed using "controller: " which is set to crText. The goal here is to set crText to chemText (which holds the text from queryData variable (`json.decode(queryParams)`). The "controller: " can be found at the very end of the code segment.

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class myClass extends StatelessWidget{
  var crText = TextEditingController();
  String chemText;

  var queryParameters = {
    "ID" :  "nfuiwnfuiwnfuinfuwnfuinw" //just one of the hashes (example)
  };


  Future<String> getData() async{


    var uri =
    Uri.https('www.myUrl.com', 'api/parameters', queryParameters);

    Icon searchIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
    var objMapUrl = "https://myUrl.com";
    Map data;
    Map queryData;
    http.Response response  = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(objMapUrl),
        headers: {

          "key" : "ifhfi2jfowjefounf893f"
        }
    );

    var queryParams = await http.get(uri, headers: {
      "key" : "ifhfi2jfowjefounf893f"

    });

    //data = json.decode(response.body);

    //print(data["hashes"]);
    // print( data["names"]);
    // print(data); //prints hashes

    //query parameters

    queryData = json.decode(queryParams.body);
    //print(queryData);

    chemText = queryData.toString();
    print(chemText);

    return chemText;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0, vertical: 8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),

          ),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                  child: TextFormField(

                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    onFieldSubmitted: (term){
                        getData();
                    },
                    cursorColor: Colors.white,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Enter  Name",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 0,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: getData,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding:  new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 200.0, 25.0, 0.0),

        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment. center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey, width: 2.0
                  )
                )
              ),
             //textfield text needs to change to the text recieved from json.decode(queryParams.body) or chemText
             controller: crText,
              maxLines: 20,

            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

`setState(() {
   crText.text = chemText
});`

somewhere. Maybe after parsing your json.

Comment: within the getData() method?

Comment: Yes, immediately after `chemText = queryData.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue and here is my solution. I don't know how well it is organized, but it works just fine.

```
TextEditingController textEditingController = 
TextEditingController();
Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
void readCurrentData() async {
data = await storage.readData();
setState(() {
  textEditingController.text = data[widget.keyOfData] ?? "";
//checking for null, since text can't be null
});
}

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
readCurrentData();
}
```